# ¿Cómo crear un fichero binario a partir de los datos introducidos por el usuario?

Tags: java, io

He hecho el siguiente código (puede que haya una forma más correcta de hacerlo, pero este no es mi problema):

```
package activitat2;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * ACTIVITAT 2 EAC 6
 * @author Montse
 */
public class EquipIns{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        EquipIns programa = new EquipIns();
        programa.inici();
    }
    public void inici(){
        System.out.println("Institutos....");
        System.out.println("1-Registrar los datos de los institutos ");
        System.out.println("2-Listar todos los institutos");
        System.out.println("3- Salir");
        System.out.println("Escoje una opción");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int punts=0;
        int enterLlegit =0;
        boolean llegit = false;
        while(!llegit){
            llegit = lector.hasNextInt();
            if (llegit){
                enterLlegit = lector.nextInt();
                switch (enterLlegit) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Registra los datos de los institutos:");
            System.out.println("Quantos institutos participan en el concurso?");
            boolean leido=false;
            int enterLlegit2 =0;
                while(!leido){
            leido = lector.hasNextInt();
            if (leido){
                enterLlegit2 = lector.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Numero total de centros: "+enterLlegit2);
            for (int j = 0; j < enterLlegit2; j++) { 
            int i=0;
            i = enterLlegit2;
            if(enterLlegit2>0){
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Introduce la info sobre el instituto:");
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Id?");
                int idInst = lector.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Nom Institut:");
                String nomInst = lector.next();
                System.out.println("Nom Equip:");
                String nomEqui = lector.next();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("::INFORMACIÓN SOBRE CENTRO INSCRITO::");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Id: " +idInst);
                System.out.println("Nom Institut: "+nomInst);
                System.out.println("Equip: "+nomEqui);
                System.out.println("Punts: "+punts);
                System.out.println();
                }
            }      

              }else{
                System.out.println("No has escrito un entero, vuelve a intentarlo");
                lector.next();
            }    
                }

   break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("has escogido listar los institutos");

   break;
        case 3:
System.out.println("Hasta la próxima!");
        break;
        default:
System.out.println("No has escrito una opción válida");
System.out.println("Fin del programa");
        break;}

            }else{
                System.out.println("No has escrito un entero, vuelve a intentarlo");
                lector.next();
            }    
        }
        lector.nextLine();


 }
}
```

Necesito crear un fichero binario a partir de este archivo donde almacenar los datos introducidos por el usuario.

Me pone en el ejercicio que tengo que introducir los registros con medida fija usando el método `void Seek()`. Máximo 48 bytes (id (4), Instituto (20), NombreEquipo (20), Puntos (4) = 48).

Es decir una vez introducidos los datos por el usuario éstos deben de grabarse en el archivo.

Posteriormente he de mostrar esta información.

---

**EDIT 1**

Tengo una duda más!

He echo la parte del código del compañero me ha puesto y me da solo un resultado por pantalla por culpa supongo de que uso la misma variable para cada respuesta del usuario.

pongo código:

```
package activitat2;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 * ACTIVITAT 2 EAC 6
 * @author Montse
 */
public class EquipIns{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        EquipIns programa = new EquipIns();
        programa.inici();
    }
    public void inici() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
         RandomAccessFile raf;
        raf = new RandomAccessFile("Resultat.bin", "rw");
        System.out.println("Institutos....");
        System.out.println("1-Registrar los datos de los institutos ");
        System.out.println("2-Listar todos los institutos");
        System.out.println("3- Salir");
        System.out.println("Escoje una opción");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int punts=0;
        int enterLlegit =0;
        boolean llegit = false;
        while(!llegit){
            llegit = lector.hasNextInt();
            if (llegit){
                enterLlegit = lector.nextInt();
                switch (enterLlegit) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Registra los datos de los institutos:");
            System.out.println("Quantos institutos participan en el concurso?");
            boolean leido=false;
            int enterLlegit2 =0;
                while(!leido){
            leido = lector.hasNextInt();
            if (leido){
                enterLlegit2 = lector.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Numero total de centros: "+enterLlegit2);
            for (int j = 0; j < enterLlegit2; j++) { 
            int i=0;
            i = enterLlegit2;
            if(enterLlegit2>0){
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Introduce la info sobre el instituto:");
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Id?");
                int idInst = lector.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Nom Institut:");
                String nomInst = lector.next();
                System.out.println("Nom Equip:");
                String nomEqui = lector.next();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("::INFORMACIÓN SOBRE CENTRO INSCRITO::");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Id: " +idInst);
                System.out.println("Nom Institut: "+nomInst);
                System.out.println("Equip: "+nomEqui);
                System.out.println("Punts: "+punts);
                System.out.println();

                 raf.seek(0);
                 raf.writeInt(idInst);
                 raf.seek(4);
                 raf.writeUTF(nomInst);
                 raf.seek(24);
                 raf.writeUTF(nomEqui);
                 raf.seek(44);
                 raf.writeInt(punts);

                }
            }      

              }else{
                System.out.println("No has escrito un entero, vuelve a intentarlo");
                lector.next();
            }    
                }

   break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("has escogido listar los institutos");
             raf.seek(0);
    System.out.println(raf.readInt());
    raf.seek(4);
    System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
    raf.seek(24);
    System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
    raf.seek(44);
    System.out.println(raf.readInt());

    raf.close();


   break;
        case 3:
System.out.println("Hasta la próxima!");
        break;
        default:
System.out.println("No has escrito una opción válida");
System.out.println("Fin del programa");
        break;}

            }else{
                System.out.println("No has escrito un entero, vuelve a intentarlo");
                lector.next();
            }    
        }
        lector.nextLine();


 }
}
```

Como lo soluciono?

Me intento explicar mejor creo que el error esta:

Cuando el usuario inserta Equipos e institutos lo guarda en la misma variable.
Así que en cuanto vuelvo a guardar ese dato en la variable me borra el anterior.

Como lo corrijo?

Podéis ponerme un ejemplo??

Es el Switch Case ( opción 1 ) Primero pido numero de Institutos que participan, Luego ID, Luego Nombre Instituto Luego nombre Equipo.

En el Switch Case 2 listo el documento! Hay alguna forma de que no me de error cuando esta vació? Poniendo algún tipo de texto diciendo que no hay institutos introducidos?

MIL GRACIAS!!

---

**EDIT 2**

```
raf.seek(0); 
raf.writeInt(id); 
raf.seek(4); 
raf.writeUTF(instituto);
 raf.seek(24); 
raf.writeUTF(equipo);
 raf.seek(44); 
raf.writeInt(puntos);
 // Leer datos 
raf.seek(0); 
System.out.println(raf.readInt()); 
raf.seek(4);
 System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
 raf.seek(24);
 System.out.println(raf.readUTF()); 
raf.seek(44);
 System.out.println(raf.readInt());
```

Otra duda más..

Cuando me pones Read UTF imagino que el UTF es por ser dato String?

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, por favor se mas especifico con tu pregunta, tu duda parece demasiado abierta. Siempre conviene que nos des más contexto y nos digas que has intentado y porque no te funciona.

Comment: A que te refieres con esto : `Me pone en el ejercicio que tengo que intruducir los registros con medida fija. Pone que de 20. Máximo 48 bytes ( id ( 4 ) , Instituto (20), NombreEquipo ( 20 ) Puntos (4) = 48. usando el método void Seek. `

Comment: Hola @Montse para mejorar tu pregunta te recomiendo que leas: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En especial por favor mejora el título

Comment: Por favor, edita el título para que dé una pista sobre cuál es el problema. Y no es necesario incluir la palabra "ayuda", si estás aquí ya sabemos que la necesitas. :-)

Comment: Y lo siento por no explicarme bien.. pero es la indicación que tenía en el ejercicio.. podría ser más explícita si entendiera que se pide..

Sobre el titulo es un Archivo Bin lo que tengo que acabar realizando y la duda viene por eso. Por que no he echo ningún archivo BIN.

Comment: Jasilva: Ha respuesto un compañero más abajo. No entiendia yo tampoco pero así se me solicitaba en el ejercicio.

Por lo que entiendo si pido ID podré ocupar los 4 primeros Bytes.. y así etc..

Comment: @jasilva gracias por la edición!

Comment: Hola, @MontseMkd He actualizado mi respuesta. :D Espero ayude.

Comment: Gracias @PaulVargas ya lo tengo!! mil gracias! :)

Comment: @MontseMkd revertí tus dos últimas ediciones porque no es necesario editar la pregunta para indicar que ya está solucionado. Basta con tener una respuesta aceptada para que se considere solucionado.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Gracias Carlos.. es que soy nueva... supongo que se nota.. lo siento! Como vi gente que ponía en espera.. Pensé que quizás tenía que ponerlo.. :S

Comment: @MontseMkd entonces te recomiendo que leas el [Recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y toda el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) en específico la sección sobre [Preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Gracias @CarlosMuñoz ayer ya le eche un ojo! 

Creo que mi error está en no hacer la pregunta y punto. Mi problema es que hago una pregunta pero luego hago más en relación a esa duda y eso no gusta mucho.. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para poder utilizar el método `seek`, necesitas una instancia, para este caso en particular,  de [`java.io.RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Esta clase se utiliza para acceder a un archivo de forma aleatoria, ya sea para lectura o escritura.

El método `seek` pone el puntero del archivo —desde cual se leerá o escribirá— en la posición indicada por `pos`. Esta posición indica el número de bytes a desplazarse a través del archivo, donde 0 es el principio de este.

El siguiente código ejemplifica el uso de la clase `java.io.RandomAccessFile` y su método `seek`:

- *Código:*

  ```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("test.bin", "rw");

      int id = 1;
      String instituto = "ABC DEF";
      String equipo = "GHI JKL";
      int puntos = 10;

      // Escribir datos
      raf.seek(0);
      raf.writeInt(id);
      raf.seek(4);
      raf.writeUTF(instituto);
      raf.seek(24);
      raf.writeUTF(equipo);
      raf.seek(44);
      raf.writeInt(puntos);

      // Leer datos
      raf.seek(0);
      System.out.println(raf.readInt());
      raf.seek(4);
      System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
      raf.seek(24);
      System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
      raf.seek(44);
      System.out.println(raf.readInt());

      raf.close();

  }
  ```
- *Salida*:

  ```
  1
  ABC DEF
  GHI JKL
  10
  ```

---

[image: new] *UPDATE*

1. Si planeas escribir varias veces *ese* mismo bloque de 48 bytes, necesitas desplazarte el número de bytes correspondiente. Por ejemplo, podrías añadir la variable `pos` para ir guardando la siguiente posición de escritura. Es decir.

   ```
   for (int i = 0, pos = 0; i < enterLlegit2; i++) {

       // Entrada de datos ...

       // Escritura de datos

       raf.seek(pos);
       raf.writeInt(id);
       pos += 4;

       raf.seek(pos);
       raf.writeUTF(instituto);
       pos += 20;

       raf.seek(pos);
       raf.writeUTF(equipo);
       pos += 20;

       raf.seek(pos);
       raf.writeInt(puntos);
       pos += 4;
   }
   ```

   Algo similar puedes hacer en la lectura:

   ```
   for (int pos = 0;;) {
       try {
           raf.seek(pos);
           System.out.println(raf.readInt());
           pos += 4;

           raf.seek(pos);
           System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
           pos += 20;

           raf.seek(24);
           System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
           pos += 20;

           raf.seek(44);
           System.out.println(raf.readInt());
           pos += 4;

           System.out.println();
       } catch (EOFException e) {
           // Fin de archivo
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. `writeUTF` y `readUTF` se utilizan para la escritura o lectura de cadenas de caracteres. En Java, un `char` utiliza dos bytes. De manera que en 20 bytes, sólo puedes meter máximo 10 `char`s. UTF está más relacionado con [Unicode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) y los formatos de transformación. Básicamente se refiere a la forma de representar un carácter en bits, la cual es muy diferente entre distintos estándares de codificación de caracteres (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1).

Comment: Es que no he echo Bin pero necesitaba saber como leer y editar. Ahora voy a intentar adaptarlo a mi código! ;)

Comment: @MontseMkd Por nada. — Por cierto, dependiendo el tipo de dato que utilices, estos ocupan cierto número de bytes. Puedes ver eso en [*Primitive Data Types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Por ejemplo, un `int` ocupa 4 bytes, exactamente lo que pide el ejercicio.

Comment: gracias!! ;) Ahora ya lo entiendo! :)